# How do I increase I/O priority for a C++ process on windows

Tags: c++, windows, performance

I'm working on a project that consumes data from a piece of FPGA hardware over USB 3.0.

Right now, the buffer in the hardware is extremely small, so I have **very** little time to consume data from the hardware without getting a buffer overrun in the hardware's FIFO. In my tests, injecting a 6 millisecond sleep in the critical thread was enough to cause a overrun in the hardware buffer.

Right now, I'm *barely* managing to make things work, with a combination of pinning to a core (it turns out the OS scheduler moving my thread from one core to another was enough to cause it to overrun) and setting my thread priority as high as I can (+15, corresponds to non-admin "Realtime". Apparently values up to 31 are technically valid, but there are windows permissions issues going higher).

Basically, I'm trying to do a near-real-time thing in windows, which I realize is not the greatest idea, but that ship has sailed, unfortunately.

So, given the above, I'm interested to see if increasing the I/O priority can possibly help.

How can I (programatically) increase the IO priority for a process on windows?

Comment: I feel for you. One high priority task taking a bit too long and the jig is up , and there are things in windows that you cannot elevate above. That said, does [`SetPriorityClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setpriorityclass) look like what you're after?

Comment: @user4581301 - I was never able to get that particular call to not return permissions errors. I'm using `SetThreadPriority()` and it seems to work, though.

Comment: From the docs, `SetPriorityClass` seems to require the `PROCESS_SET_INFORMATION` access right, and I couldn't get a clear idea how to get that. I'm spawning my threads via `std::thread`, and it looks like to use `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` for threading instead to manipulate my thread config flags, and that would involve rewriting most of the threading infrastructure I have in place already.

Comment: Which API are you using to read the data? Just a blocking ReadFile() or similar?

Comment: Something in LibUSB. It's a vendor provided library that wraps a USB device. I'm actually not totally certain I/O priority will even affect it (I think USB I/O is grouped under I/O priority in windows), but I don't have many ideas left at this point.

Comment: Really, I think the proper solution here is to lean on our FPGA guy to add a better FIFO, but that'll take considerably longer then just fiddling with priorities (and why not try both!).

Comment: I’ve looked at libusb for 5 minutes and didn’t like what I saw. They appear to use overlapped IO with WaitForMultipleObjects, and IMO they lock their critical sections too much. You could try implementing IOCP, or use higher level thread pool API, to interact with the driver. You don’t need to port the complete libusb, just the routines you use.

Comment: All that stuff in in a vendor DLL I have no access to. I'm *pretty* sure it uses LibUSB, but that's kind of irrelevant here, as even if it does, I can't make changes. All I have is a header and a .dll.

Comment: Don't use Windows, write a kernel mode driver, or use a bigger buffer in hardware.

Comment: Sure, you tell my management that, @rustyx.